# Handle SIGINT and child wait with select! without blocking

Tags: rust

I have rust module that sets up a SIGINT catch handler with `crossbeam_channel`:

```rust
fn sigint_channel() -> Result<Receiver<bool>, ctrlc::Error> {
    let (sender, receiver) = unbounded();

    // Handle Ctrl+C (aka SIGINT)
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
        warn!("Got SIGINT, stopping the Child ..");
        let _ = sender.send(true);
    })?;

    Ok(receiver)
}
```

The returned `Receiver` is then passed to a module function that runs a system command `Child` and waits for some data to come through the `Channel`:

```rust
if let Some(child) = get_child(cmd) {
    loop {
        select! {
            recv(receiver) -> _ => {
                kill(child);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Code never reached
        child.try_wait();
    }
}
```

Now the program get stuck at `select!`. Even if the child terminates, the code still waiting in `select!`. The program will exit now only if I press Ctrl+C.

I had the idea of creating another channel between the parent process and the child, or using threads to run the child, but I am not sure how to do that. Any ideas on how to make this possible?

I read that `tokio` it can solve this issue, but I don't understand it well since I have only 2 months of experience with Rust.

## Edit

`Child` and `get_child()` is just a function that `spawn`s a `Command` and returns the `Child` object.

I cannot provide the exact code, but the last instruction is `cmd.spawn()`, the system command to run is a program that can take too much time. So I need to press Ctrl+C at any time or wait for it to exit on its own.

Comment: I don't think you're using `select!` right. First of all, it doesn't make much sense with only one arm. Secondly, it's meant for use with multiple channels.

Comment: I posted the wrong code, check the edit, I don't know exactly how to handle the one channel in my case

Comment: Seems like `child.try_wait()` should be inside the `select!` as a second arm, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @cdhowie How to code that ? I did not find a way to add it as an arm to `select`

Comment: What is `Child`? What is `get_child()`? Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check Edit for more information, I hope it makes it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```rust
loop {
    select! {
        // If we get the kill signal
        recv(receiver) -> _ => {
            // Kill child
            kill(child);
            break;
        }
        // Otherwise keep waiting for child to finish
        default(Duration::from_millis(100)) => {
            match child.try_wait() {
                Ok(Some(_)) => break,
                Ok(None) => (),
                Err(e) => panic!("error when waiting: {e}"),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca26b821655f3c5cd3d7182b929cbd4f)

Comment: It worked, but can you add some explaination about `default` and how `select!` in my case works ?